# Intercept opening android setting of apps with BroadcastReceiver

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver, android-manifest

I declared in AndroidManifest permission and receiver

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REAL_GET_TASKS"/>

<receiver android:name=".UninstallIntentReceiver">
            <intent-filter android:priority="0">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUERY_PACKAGE_RESTART" />
                <data android:scheme="package" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

And here is my java class receiver

```
public class UninstallIntentReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    String[] packageNames = intent.getStringArrayExtra("android.intent.extra.PACKAGES");

    if(packageNames!=null){
        for(String packageName: packageNames){
            Log.d("User selected: ",packageName);
        }
    }
}
```

When I open settings of other apps it works well - I get notification 
 (I can see in logs package name of chosen application), but
when I open settings my own application, I don't receive anything

Comment: That `Intent` action is undocumented AFAICT. It may work like lots of other package-related broadcasts, that it is not sent to the specific app that was affected by the broadcast.

Comment: hey, thanks for your answer, I just found out that I can get notification only if I choose in this menu https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nqu3Z.jpg only stopped applications. Could you explain me why does it work like this ?

Comment: As I wrote, that `Intent` action is undocumented AFAICT. If you find documentation on it, perhaps the documentation will explain this behavior. If you do not find documentation on it, perhaps you should not be relying upon it, as it may not exist in all relevant versions of Android (e.g., manufacturers may not use it).

Comment: sorry, do you mean Intent in java code ? because method onReceive totally does not work and it does not depend on parameter Intent
I already set logs at once after public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

Comment: I mean that `android.intent.action.QUERY_PACKAGE_RESTART` is undocumented, AFAICT.